# Remove ticks piechart NVD3

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

Is there way to remove ticks from pie chart in NVD3 `rcharts`?

## Example

```
p4 <- nPlot(~ cyl, data = mtcars, type = 'pieChart')
p4
```

gives me
[image]

I know that there is `p4$chart(showLegend  = FALSE)` which remove legend but i cant find way to remove tiks and labels on it

Comment: there's a 'showLabels' flag in the documentation http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pieChart

Comment: @OsmanMazinov ok, its what i need